E flat tuning - adjust bass?
if my guitarist is playing his Strat in Eb should I be tuning down my bass or keep standard tuning and transpose? Which is more common?

Usually entire bands tune to the same set of pitches. There are a few good reasons for this. One is everything you play will be in the same key for all of you, no need to transpose anything. Another reason is if the music is riff based with guitars and bass sometimes playing in unison any riff that uses the open low E string can be played the same way on all the instruments without having to do any octave transpositions. There is also the fact that riffs that might use open strings for a certain sound or effect will be consistent across all the instruments.
In some cases guitarists may have two instruments, one tuned standard, one tuned down a semitone. If that’s the case you might consider using two basses so you don’t have to retune between songs, which is a hassle and can also cause your bass to drift out of tune more easily from all the adjusting.
In the end it’s your choice to transpose or tune down but I think tuning down is easier overall, even if you have a 5 string bass with extra low notes.

"Usually entire bands tune to the same set of pitches", but they just don't tell it to the drummer and the singer, as the former couldn't care less, while the latter wouldn't even notice it. Or was it the other way around?

@musicamante Yep and yep. Actually singers might like that extra semitone of range…

You just need to tell them, even if you don't actually do it ;-)

Even without riffs, the guitar will very likely at some point play an Eb-chord, using an open lowest string. At this point, the lowest Eb available on a 4-string bass in standard tuning is actually the same octave Eb the guitar is already playing, removing most of the depth that a bass player normally can add to chords.

Nice answer. A thought occurred, but I've never tried it (don't particularly like or use them). How about tuning down, and using a capo when needed, on bass? Ever tried?

@Tim I haven’t tried it. It may work for some but it wouldn’t for me because I play all over the instrument so using a capo would just change where I’m used to playing everything.  I can wrap my head around playing what is to me an E and hearing an Eb  but I can’t think of  for example, the 12th fret as the 11th fret if that makes sense. I only use a capo on guitar mainly when I want to use open string chords  in other keys and registers.

Might as well follow the guitarist. There are two main reasons for tuning down - playing a little lower (obvious), and having less tension in the strings.
If the guitarist is going to play in 'E', in reality E♭, then with you tuning down, you'll have the advantage of using open 'E', which would make your life easier. I solved that problem years ago by playing a 5 string bass!!
Another alternative occurred to me - fit a device which when switched (physically) drops the string a semitone. Hipshot is one such that comes to mind.
